# how to solve number Pelindrom by using for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to solve this giving undesired result, getting false always.

```js
function isPelindrom(n) {
    if (n < 0) return false;
    let orgNum = n
    let reversed = 0

    for (let x = 0; x <= orgNum; x++) {
        let lastDigit = orgNum % 10;
        reversed = (reversed * 10) + lastDigit;
        orgNum = parseInt(orgNum / 10);
    }
    return n == reversed
}


isPelindrom(12321)
```

Comment: The problem is the for loop, you're dividing by 10 but `x` is still adding 1 to it's value so when it get's to the last digits `x >= 1` as `x` would be 3 or 4 by that point

Comment: thats i know ,how to over come this issue?

Comment: Do you mean to use the word palidrome?

Answer (score 3):

```js
function Palindrome(num) {
  let numToStringArray = num.toString();

  const reversed = numToStringArray.toString().split('').reverse().join('');

  return numToStringArray === reversed ? "It's a palindrome" : "It's not a palindrome";
}

console.log(Palindrome(989));
console.log(Palindrome(23));
console.log(Palindrome(9));
```

```js
function Palindrome(number) {

    var temp = number, final = 0;
    while (number > 0) {
        rem = number % 10;
        number = parseInt(number / 10);
        final = final * 10 + rem;
    }

    if (temp == final) {
        return "It's Palindrome";
    }
    else {
        return "It's not Palindrome";
    }

}

console.log(Palindrome(989));
console.log(Palindrome(23));
console.log(Palindrome(9));
```

Comment: no, i don't want to convert to string thats the catch.

Comment: @atulsingh That is something you should mention in your question _before_ someone spends time on it.

Comment: @atulsingh, I have added another way of doing this into my answer. Check this.

Comment: thanks  but   @ShahnawazHossan   i want to do with for loop

Comment: @atulsingh, bro this is not fair of doing something like this. You should have mentioned in your question that in which way you would like to implement this. Don't do this anymore, please.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it to a for loop and either set it to greater or equal to 0.1 or just greater than 0.

```js
function isPelindrom(n) {
  if (n < 0) return false;
  let orgNum = n
  let reversed = 0

  while(orgNum>=0.1) {
    let lastDigit = orgNum % 10;
    reversed = (reversed * 10) + lastDigit;
    orgNum = parseInt(orgNum / 10);
  }
  return n == reversed
}


console.log(isPelindrom(12321))
console.log(isPelindrom(12322))
```

Comment: while loop its working , i want to solve this using for loop .

Answer (score 1):

Does `while` loop count?

```js
const isPalindrome = num => {
  const origin = num
  let reversed = 0
  while (num !== 0) {
    const digit = num % 10
    reversed = reversed * 10 + digit
    num = Math.floor(num / 10)
  }

  return origin === reversed
}

console.log(isPalindrome(12321))
console.log(isPalindrome(12331))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
function isPelindrom(n) {
  if (n < 0) return false;
  let orgNum = n
  let reversed = 0

  var numberOfDigits = 0;
  for(i = orgNum; i > 1; ++i){
      ++numberOfDigits;
      i = Math.floor(i/10);
  }

  for (let x = 0; x < numberOfDigits; x++) {
    let lastDigit = orgNum % 10;
    reversed = (reversed * 10) + lastDigit;
    orgNum = parseInt(orgNum / 10);
  }
  return n == reversed
}
```